# HTML Version of cfinclude

Tags: html

Is there a simple HTML command that does the same thing as cfinclude?

I am trying to avoid replicating content for static HTML pages

Comment: You could use shtml (old school). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: @lharby — The question said "static HTML pages". SSI is a dynamic server side technique.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

The closest HTML has is [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), which will display another document in a sub-window, but that has its own scrollbars and independent DOM.

You could use client side JavaScript to fetch content and modify the DOM with it (or embed the content in the JS and write it out inline as the script loads).

If you want static pages, then you are usually best off generating them using a template language at build time (i.e. generating static pages from templates before you upload them to the server). Tools that can help you achieve this include [ttree](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) and [Assemble](http://assemble.io/).